# Angular Chart Radar chart. Событие при нажатии на название оси

Tags: angularjs, chart.js

Необходимо при наведении на названия осей в Radar chart менять указатель и при нажатии переходить на другую страницу. По примерам в документациях [Angular Chart](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js) и [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/docs) ни чего не нашел. Поиск результатов не дал.

Код контроллера на angularJs:

```
startViewApp.controller('StartViewCategor1Controller', function ($scope, $http, $timeout, $window, chartServices, blockUI, toastr, toastrConfig) {   
        var valChart = function (val) {
            if (val == null) return 'Данные отсутствуют';
            else return val;
        }

        var tooltipLabel = function (str) {
            if (str == 'Фактическое значение процесса') return 'Значение процесса';
            if (str == 'Фактическое значение процесса за прошлый год') return 'Значение процесса за прошлый год';
            else return str;
        }

        var myBlockUICat1 = blockUI.instances.get('myBlockUICat1');
        myBlockUICat1.start("Данные загружаются");
        chartServices.getDataChart1().then(function (r) {
            if (r.data.error) {
                myBlockUICat1.stop();
                toastr['error']('Невозможно отобразить график основных процессов!!!')
                $window.alert(response.data.error);
            }
            else {
                $scope.labels = r.data.NameSokrProcessList;

                var l = r.data.NameProcessList;
                $scope.options =
                    {
                        title: {
                            display: true,
                            text: 'Основные процессы',
                            fontSize: 20
                        },
                        tooltips: {
                            position: 'nearest',
                            //mode: 'label',
                            callbacks: {
                                title:
                                    function (tooltipItems, data) {
                                        return tooltipItems[0].xLabel;
                                    }
                                ,
                                label:
                                    function (tooltipItems, data) {
                                        return tooltipLabel(data.datasets[tooltipItems.datasetIndex].label) +
                                        " : " +
                                        valChart(data.datasets[tooltipItems.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItems.index]);
                                    }
                            }
                        },
                        legend:
                            {
                                display: true
                            },
                        type: 'radar',
                        scale: {
                            ticks:
                                {
                                    beginAtZero: true,
                                    fontSize: 13
                                },
                            pointLabels: {
                                fontSize: 13
                            }
                        }
                    };
                $scope.data = [
                      r.data.ValueProcessList,
                      r.data.ValueProcessListPrev,
                      [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
                ];
                $scope.dataset = [
                        {
                            pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)",
                            pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(0,0,0,1)",
                        }
                ]
                $scope.datasetOverride = [
                      {
                          label: "Фактическое значение процесса",
                          backgroundColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.5)",
                          borderWidth: 3,
                          type: 'radar',
                          pointRadius: 7,
                          pointHitRadius: 10
                      },
                      {
                          label: "Фактическое значение процесса за прошлый год",
                          backgroundColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.4)",
                          borderWidth: 3,
                          type: 'radar',
                          pointRadius: 7,
                          pointHitRadius: 10
                      },
                      {
                          label: "Норматив",
                          backgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.0)",
                          type: 'radar',
                          pointRadius: 0,
                          pointHitRadius: 10
                      }
                ];
                myBlockUICat1.stop();
            }
        }).catch(function (error) {
            myBlockUICat1.stop();
            $window.alert(error);
            toastr['error']('Невозможно отобразить график основных процессов!!!!')
        });
    });
```

Вызов контроллера на странице HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="StartViewCategor1Controller" class="cont-border" block-ui="myBlockCat1">
   <canvas id="polar-area1" class="chart chart-radar" chart-data="data" 
         chart-labels="labels" chart-options="options" chart-series="series" 
         chart-colors="colors" chart-dataset-override="datasetOverride"></canvas>
</div>
```